# Integer Linear Programming approximate solution with CBC

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have an ILP (Integer Linear Programming) problem, and am using CBC to solve it.

My goal is to compute the best approximate solution in less than 30 seconds.

I tried to use the following parameters: maxSeconds = 30 but it doesn't always work. Sometimes, the algorithm returns a non-integer solution after 30 seconds.

I also tried ratioGap = 0.01, hOptions = 1 in order to get an approximate solution. However, it sometimes takes more than 30 seconds to get it.

How could I get the best possible integer solution (not necessarily the optimum) in less than 30 seconds?

Comment: Maybe it takes sometimes more than 30 seconds to find the first integer feasible solution.

Comment: Try to turn off preprocessing or adjust it somehow (I didn't try it with CDC bit it did work with CPLEX).